How to tile floor-tile texture on flat plane. Also its blurry
I've looked at loads of different questions / ask / etc, but they either don't work for me or (more commonly) I just don't understand what it's telling me.
I'm extremely new to Blender, maybe 1 month? And I need you to explain to me like a big dumb stupid baby, because I can't seem to understand more than that. XD
I'm trying to make an animation, and I want the floor, which is a flat plane, to look like floor-tile. The bit of UV I have is 3x3 tiles, and it SHOULD be seamless, but its not. (It is VERY small, 30x30 pixels). I managed to get it to "work" by making a bunch of loop cuts (I thought there was a way to use subdivide, but that makes the whole thing circular.) but it has a weird seam line that is very visible, which, since I'm able to move the points onto individual pixels- weird to me. Shouldn't I be able to get it exact?
Is it BECAUSE its such a small texture? I know I can probably just make the image itself bigger, like. 9x9 instead of 3x3. is that what I would have to do? I managed to get the wall to look pretty decent.
Also- is there a way for it to scale up properly? It keeps making all the pixels blurry, and I know in Photoshop and stuff you can change the scale from (whatever) to (nearest neighbor). Something about making it so it doesn't use antialiasing when scaling. (It's pixelart.)
I saw some stuff talking about nodes, but, uhh... I've yet to get there in my tutorials, so if that's the solution then I guess I'll have to fix it later. I've got a basic node setup that works for shading or something I copied directly from someone else, but if I have to add more to the nodes, uhh......
Edit:
Sorry for not being more clear. The only way I can manage to tile my image (which isn't working because of the seam lines, which I thought I'd successfully edited into the post last night, but I realized today I didn't.)
The only way I could manage to get this to work was my dividing my plane using loop cuts so it was 8x8. (8 rows and 8 columns). I then overlapped the faces in the UV so they were all exactly the same, therefor manually 'tiling' my texture. I know there is a better way to do this, but even if there isn't a better way, I should be able to remove the seam in the texture, since the image itself is a seamless image. I have extra pixels around it to try to fix the seam issue, because otherwise I was able to see the background color.
Sorry, I wasn't trying to ask everyone to teach me nodes or UV mapping or anything, I'm just trying to get this one issue (the seam) to get fixed. (Well, and also the blurriness, but I figured that would either be easy, or part of the solution.)
Edit Edit:
It's fixed! The seam was caused by the antialiasing, so once I changed the Interpolation from Linear to Closest like Gordon said, it fixed the issue, and I was able to tile it properly!
Thank you so much!
(I'm sure there is still an easier way to tile an image, but my problem is solved for now so I'm happy! <3)


It's OK to be new to Blender and to not understand stuff and most of people answering questions here expect that, but you need to communicate a lot more clearly. Form a clear specific single question, state what you have done exactly to atchieve you goals (step by step maybe?..) and how it failed, add images/sketches of what you are trying to atchieve, screenshots of your attempts and Blender's UI and settings you are working with and you may get a good answer. You should edit the question because it's not possible to understand now.

It might sometimes be helpful to share the file in addition to screenshots if possible. You could use https://blend-exchange.com/ for that.

Please don't edit the title with "Fixed" or "Solved" or anything like that. It's not how this works on Blender Stack Exchange. If you have the answer mark it as accepted, if you figure it out on your own, it's expected here you would provide the solution as an answer even if it's your own question.

BLURRY
To fix the blurriness, I followed what Gordon Brinkmann said, and changed the image texture from Linear to Closest. Since my tile was a pixel image, I wanted the pixels to scale correctly, and that is what does it.
TILE

I have a single, flat plane. No subdivision or loop-cuts needed. Just a blank, flat plane. Add the tile image and put the UV to fit your tile (mine is a square.)

In the Shader tab, using the nodes, I have a Texture Coordinate node, which I can set to UV to repeat a single image, then I use the Mapping node, connecting the Texture Coordinate > UV to the Mapping  > Vector.
Playing with the scale repeats the UV texture you've used. You want to be in Render View to see it.
Ta-Da!

If you have such small textures and you don't want them to get blurry, change the Interpolation in the Image Texture node from the default Linear to Closest instead.

For everything else, how the Subdivision Surface modifier works, how texturing and UV mapping etc. works: this is a very broad question and cannot be simply answered in one step. This site is more about focusing on single specific issues per question. Being completely new is fine, but I would highly recommend you watch a lot of beginner tutorials to get a grasp on how things work in Blender, also to get to know terminology which makes it easier to ask questions which will be understood by users on this platform.
